# JS - Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined even it's got that object

Tags: javascript, json

I want to check if the user(chat.chatid) is already in the array(ids.json) else add him into that. For this i am using 'includes'

```
//chat.chatid = 469750202
//owner(Property) = { users: ["469750202", "638606486"] }


var ids = Bot.getProperty('owner')

if (!ids) {
    var ids = {
        users: []
    }
};
if (!ids.users.includes(chat.chatid)) {
    ids.users.push(chat.chatid);
    Bot.setProperty("owner", ids, "json");
};
Bot.sendMessage('some text');
```

Comment: Your code is working perfectly fine if you have a `chat` object with `chatid` key. What is the error that you are getting and in which statement?

Comment: when i *inspect* the `ids`, by getting it from saved property it shows only last users id `chat.chatid` instead of showing this one `{ users: ["469750202" , 
"638606486"] }`

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Please format it as a snippet and make sure that the error you observe in your local environment also get thrown when you run the code in the Stack Overflow snippet. I see you're a new contributor - would you need assistance doing that?

Comment: In that case you need to start making use of your debugging tools.

Comment: Nino Filiu - Is it free of charge?)

Answer (score 0):

You need verify that your `ids` really have value:

{ users: ["469750202", "638606486"] }

Try run:

```
var ids = Bot.getProperty('owner');
Bot.sendMessage( JSON.stringfy(ids) );
```

It is possible that
ids.users is undefined

Comment: I tried what you said, but it performs an error `JSON.stringfy is not a function`